spring ai use ollama qwen2.5:14B，How to make function call return specified content
i use spring ai, ollama 0.3.13, qwen2.5:14b
My current idea is to have a JS pop-up confirm before executing the function call operation，
I don't know if function call was used in this request, and I can't return the specified content
my function call:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Description("edit username")
@Service
public class EditUserNameFunction implements Function<EditUserNameFunction.Request, EditUserNameFunction.Response> {



    @Data
    public static class Request {
        @JsonProperty(required = true, value = "newName")
        @JsonPropertyDescription(value = "newName")
        String newName;
    }

    public record Response(String message) {
    }



    @Override
    public Response apply(Request request) {
        return new Response(String.format("""
                 {
                            "action": "editUser",
                            "parameter": %s
                        }""",request.newName));
    }

}


controller
    @PostMapping(value = "/test/ai",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ChatResponse> test2(@RequestBody List<MessageDto> messageDtoList) throws IOException {
// do sth....
        return chatModel.stream(new Prompt(messages, OllamaOptions.
                 builder()
                .withFunction("editUserNameFunction")
                .withModel(model)
                .build()));
}

I hope to return the specified JSON content to the frontend after running function call，The front-end can perform different operations based on the returned content, such as popping up a confirmation box, popping up a failed message, popping up a successful message, and so on

There does not appear to be any JavaScript in the code you posted.

JavaScript is not important, it just gets content from Java

Well then why did you use the "JavaScript" tag on the question? It is important to be accurate with the question tags if you want to get good answers (or any answers).

JavaScript tag has been removed

I have a hard time understand what you are trying to do and what the question is.
You have a user defined function. You also want to return some JSON to the frontend. Fine. What is the actual problem?
